# Redshift Serverless inbound connections timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-serverless

i made a redshift data warehouse with the Serverless Preview in order to make it connect to a Google Data Studio.
I opened the 5439 port to every ipv6 and ipv4 on the security group, tho it still timeout.
I don't know what to do, is it possible that serverless is not publicly opened? I am forced to create a cluster for open Redshift to external connections?

Thank you very much

Comment: From [Connecting to Amazon Redshift Serverless - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/serverless-connecting.html): _"The serverless endpoint connects to the serverless environment in your AWS account in the current AWS Region. The serverless endpoint runs in a VPC and is not publicly accessible."_

Comment: I don't know how i missed that, so I essentially need to create a cluster, or i can in some way expose the data to google data studio? (for example creating a custom connector to an aws lambda exposed by API gateway)
Thank you very much for the response

Comment: You would need to somehow create a 'jump box' or reverse proxy to forward traffic from the Internet to Redshift Serverless. Effectively, you'd need a resource (eg EC2 instance) that is publicly accessible that can receive requests and forward them to Redshift Serverless. You can protect it with IP limitations in the Security Group, and of course login authentication is still required.

Comment: On the `Connecting to Amazon Redshift Serverless` page you can find a CloudFormation stack to deploy a load balancer for connecting from a public network: https://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-downloads/docs-downloads/redshift-nlb.yml

Comment: You need to go to the database configuration of your redshift cluster and set Publicly accessible to enabled. See @Tomas answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

You can now make your serverless endpoint publicly accessible:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/serverless-connecting.html

> Creating a publicly accessible Amazon Redshift Serverless instance and connecting to it
> Connect to a publicly accessible Amazon Redshift Serverless instance

Basically you need to set the setting Public Accessible when you create the workgroup. By default it's false.